# How can I read in long (or wide) data sets in SAS using a simple input statement?

Tags: arrays, loops, input, sas, transpose

I'd like to transpose data using do loops without using proc transpose. The data sets in question are .csv files that look like this:

| SiteID 1 | AQS 3 | Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max1 |  |  |
| MinSaleValue0.3 |  |  |
| Count23 |  |  |

| SiteID 1 | AQS 3 | Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max3 |  |  |
| MinSaleValue0.028 |  |  |
| Count22 |  |  |

| SiteID 1 | AQS 3 | Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max10 |  |  |
| MinSaleValue0.0005 |  |  |
| Count20 |  |  |

In other words, I have variables Max, MinSaleValue,and Count that I'm interested in, which are separated by headers indicating SiteID, AQS, and Code.

Similarly, I'm kind of confused as to how to make wide data long when I have headers in the way.

In that case, I have something that looks like:

| SiteID | AQS | Code | Max1 | Min1 | Count1 | Max2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0.5 | 23 | 5 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0.02003 | 21 | 7 | ... |

Note: the trailing is to indicate that I have a repetition of 200 max, min, and count values for the proceeding columns. So after the header containing siteID, AQS, and Code, I have (max1,min1,count1,max2,min2,count2,max3,min3,count3.....and so on).
I'd like to make this wide data long as well using arrays and do loops, but am running into a similar issue with not knowing how to read in the data.

For the long data:

Reading in the data like this:

```
data InputDS.LongData;
infile RawData('Long Data.csv') dlm='092C'x dsd truncover firstobs=7 *skip 7 lines to get rid of descriptive header;
*input _SiteID _AQS _Code;
```

returns a table that looks likle this:

| SiteID 1 | AQS 3 | Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |

| SiteID 1 | AQS 3 | Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |

| SiteID 1 | AQS 3 | Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |

.
.
.
and so on, and I have about 200 of these observations.

In other words, I preserved the headers but not the long skinny data I would like to widen with arrays and a do-loop. My final result would have the SiteID, AQS, Code, and the three variables (max, min, count) for all 200 observations.

If the headers separating these didn't exist (or if I only had site ID to worry about), this seems like it would be simple enough. However, I'm kind of at a loss with what to do with the headers.

For the wide data:

For this one, I'm not even sure how to get in all the variables, I have this so far:

```
data InputDS.WideData;
infile RawData('Wide Data.csv') dlm=',' dsd truncover firstobs=6 *skip descriptive header of data by reading in from 6th line onwards;
*input _all_;*
```

but not really sure where to proceed from here. I'd like to read in every single variable present in the data set, and then use my method get all the max values, min values, and counts into their own arrays and use a do loop to "lengthen" this data, but I already got stuck with respect to how to read in this data.

Comment: Where in the csv are the min max count values?  Are they part of the **row header**? Are the values in the AQS3 and Code2 columns the same for all rows of a section (a section being the lines belonging to a header).  If you input and accumulate rows with name=value pairs, you will want to SORT and TRANSPOSE after reading the csv(s)

Comment: Please correct your example so it is clear where the output values are coming from.  Put some values into the AQS3 and CODE2 cells.  Also make sure the variable names match on the input and the output.  For example your inputs have variables AQS3 and CODE2 but your outputs have AQS and CODE.   Your inputs have MAX1, MAX3 and MAX10 but your outputs have MAX1 and MAX2.

Comment: Can you show the actual text of the example CSV files instead of those tabular things you have now?

Comment: @Tom There is no input under AQS2 and CODE2. Those are the "headers" 
So I'm trying to get the row to look like: (SiteID1,AQS3,CODE2,Max1,MinSaleValue0.3,Count23) for the first row, for the second row I would like 
(SideID1, AQS3,CODE2, Max3, MinSaleValue0.028,Count22)...and so on, for about 300 of these. Keep in mind that SiteID1 is one specific value of SiteID and AQS3 is a specific value of AQS, CODE2 is a specific value of CODE. These can vary, but for my data set all of them are the same. I have SiteID, AQS, and Code in a .csv file taking up three columns, and underneath it, have (cont)

Comment: (cont) the "skinny/long" data of Max,MinSaleValue, and Count. I'd like to transpose (with a do loop and array) that part and then append it to the SideID/AQS3/CODE2 part preceding it. I have about 200 of these observations (so 200 max values, 200 min sale values, 200 counts) and in my final dataset I'd like 200 rows to show with each of these valules in their own columns, along with the appropriate code, aqs, and siteID.

Comment: @Richard The min, max, count values are 3x1 just nested under the 1x3 (SiteID, AQS,Code) row. I would like to transpose the min,max,count values so that it is 1x3 also, and then attach it next to the preceding row that had the 1x3 (SiteID, AQS, Code) so that I get a row that is 1x6. To do this, I have to read in the data with a simple list input somehow and then use an array and a do loop.

Comment: If the part under 1x3 is 3x1 how do you know the names and values.  Do you actually mean 3x2 ?

Comment: Please show a sample of the csv file as text in the question, rather than tabular data.

Comment: If the input text files have no numbers in them then where did the numbers in the output file come from?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have a CSV file like this where the variable name and the value are smushed into a single cell.

```
options parmcards=csv1;
filename csv1 temp;
parmcards4;
SiteID 1,AQS 3,Code 2
Max 1,,
MinSaleValue 0.3,,
Count 23,,
;;;;
```

You can read that by first reading the cell value into a character variable and then parsing out the name and the value.

```
data file1;
  infile csv1 dsd truncover ;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    input dummy :$50. @ ;
    SiteID=scan(dummy,2,' ');
    input dummy @;
    AQS=input(scan(dummy,2,' '),32.);
    input dummy @;
    Code=input(scan(dummy,2,' '),32.);
    retain SiteID AQS Code ;
    delete;
  end;
  input dummy ;
  value=input(scan(dummy,2,' '),32.);
  varname=scan(dummy,1,' ');
  drop dummy;
run;
```

Which will result in a dataset like this:

[image: regular dataset]

You can then use PROC TRANSPOSE to make a wide dataset.

```
proc transpose data=file1 out=wide1(drop=_name_) ;
  by siteid aqs code ;
  id varname;
  var value;
run;
```

[image: transposed dataset]

To get your extremely wide dataset you will need to add another variable that can be used as the SUFFIX on the variable names.  Perhaps it is part of the FILENAME of the CSV file?  Or just a simple count of the number of files read?  Once you have that variable then just include it in the ID statement of the PROC TRANSPOSE step.